# Graphics issue in linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, graphics

I installed Linux mint 18.3 now. When I am scrolling, scrolling is not so smooth. I am attaching 2 screen shots in this regard.

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not married to mint (or at least to cinnamon), I recommend switching distros (or desktops). I had a similar issue with cinnamon on some older computers I manage. I switched over to gnome classic, and I find that it runs much smoother, and that there is very little or no feature loss.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I switch over to gnome classic? Thanks

Comment: It may be easiest to switch to Ubuntu or Debian. Barring that, however, run this command from terminal: `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions gnome-tweak-tool` . That should install a bunch of packages, including gdm (which you should probably use as your window manager just for compatibility's sake). After a restart, you should be good to go.